# How to get something specific from a tuple

Tags: python, gstreamer

Let's say i have this tuple:

```
(<GstStructure at 0xb270e080>, ' audio/x-raw, rate=(int)44100, layout=(string)interleaved, format=(string){ S8, S16LE, S32LE, S24LE, F32LE, F64LE }, channels=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ]; audio/x-raw, rate=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ], channels=(int)1, format=(string)F32LE, layout=(string)interleaved; audio/x-raw, rate=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ], layout=(string)interleaved, format=(string){ S8\x91\x00\x00\x00@\x00p\xb2@\x00p\xb2LE, S24LE, F32LE, F64LE }, channels=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ]')
```

I want to get the rate, but the tuple really only has two elements. How can i get the rate?

Comment: Im guessing `mytuple[1]` then parse it?

Comment: @JakobBowyer: it could be that `mytuple[0]` has methods to provide access to readily-parsed info, but I am not certain about the API..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd value of the tuple seems to be a string representation of the GStructure object provided by the 1st value of the tuple.

You could parse the string as said above to retrieve the rate value (although 2 possible values are possible: `44100` or `[ 1, 2147483647 ]`, we suppose that `44100` is the one you want).

If you want to use the GStructure instance, according to the documentation of [GStreamer  GStructure](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-reference/class-gststructure.html) you could use the `get_value()` method:

```
your_tuple[0].get_value("rate")
```

Can you give a try ?

Comment: This is actually the best method for getting the value. I just don't know why it returns the right value but gives me this:

    in_rate = kaps[0].get_value('rate')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unknown type GstIntRange

Comment: So I don't understand : did you have the value ? Or does the line raises the exception ?

Comment: I have the value ( i printed out in_rate to which i give the value and it's there), but the program i'm running has a log and i get the TypeError in the log.

Comment: Oh ok then maybe the logger does not know how to handle a GstIntRange type value.

Answer (score 2):

```
your_tuple[1].split(', ')[1].split('=(int)')[1]
```

You get the second element of your_tuple. then you split it on ', ' which gives you:

```
[' audio/x-raw', 'rate=(int)44100', 'layout=(string)interleaved', 'format=(string){ S8', 'S16LE', 'S32LE', 'S24LE', 'F32LE', 'F64LE }', 'channels=(int)[ 1', '2147483647 ]; audio/x-raw', 'rate=(int)[ 1', '2147483647 ]', 'channels=(int)1', 'format=(string)F32LE', 'layout=(string)interleaved; audio/x-raw', 'rate=(int)[ 1', '2147483647 ]', 'layout=(string)interleaved', 'format=(string){ S8\x91\x00\x00\x00@\x00p\xb2@\x00p\xb2LE', 'S24LE', 'F32LE', 'F64LE }', 'channels=(int)[ 1', '2147483647 ]']
```

On the second element, you do another split on '=(int)', and that's the second element.

which is '44100'

Comment: `rate=(int)[ 1', '2147483647 ]`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here

Comment: I get '[ 1' . Which means that it skips the first rate. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Lets call your tuple "tuple"; then you could do something like this:

```
strings = tuple[1].split(', ') //Splitting the second item base on the ', ' delimiter
rate = strings[1][10:] //The number you want starts at the 10th character of the second object in the array
```

If the format of your stream changes you will have to parse it differently, you could also do a for loop through the array and search for "rate=(int)".

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
t = ('<GstStructure at 0xb270e080>', ' audio/x-raw, rate=(int)44100, layout=(string)interleaved, format=(string){ S8, S16LE, S32LE, S24LE, F32LE, F64LE }, channels=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ]; audio/x-raw, rate=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ], channels=(int)1, format=(string)F32LE, layout=(string)interleaved; audio/x-raw, rate=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ], layout=(string)interleaved, format=(string){ S8\x91\x00\x00\x00@\x00p\xb2@\x00p\xb2LE, S24LE, F32LE, F64LE }, channels=(int)[ 1, 2147483647 ]')
print re.findall('rate=\(int\)\[? ?(\d+),? ?(\d+)? ?\]?', t[1])
```

Which prints a list of all the numbers that have a rate=(int) before it. This regex looks really sloppy but it gets the job done.

```
[('44100', ''), ('1', '2147483647'), ('1', '2147483647')]
```